# Solve $\operatorname{cotan}(z) = 2 + i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

As the title says, I have to solve: $\operatorname{cotan}(z) = 2 + i$

I have gotten this far:

$$\tan(z) = \frac{1}{2+i} = \frac{2}{5} - \frac{1}{5}i$$

I thought, maybe writing $z=x+iy$ would work. I found the following online (via complex exponential):
$$\tan(x+iy) = \frac{\sin(2x)+i\sinh(2y)}{\cosh(2y)+\cos(2x)}.$$

But equating the real and imaginary parts does not really give me something I can work with (or is it just rough work?).
Any hints or tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: work out $\tanh iz$, then look up an expression for $\mathrm{artanh}$ in terms of $\ln$.

Comment: Thanks, but is this method also valid for tan instead of tanh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do these problems is writing $\tan$ as a quotient of complex exponentials. Let $w=\frac{2}{5}-\frac{1}{5}i$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin z}{\cos z} &= w \\
\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}} &= iw \\
\frac{1-e^{-2iz}}{1+e^{-2iz}} &=iw \\
1-e^{-2iz} &= iw(1+e^{-2iz}), \text{ so } e^{-2iz} = \frac{1-iw}{1+iw}.
\end{align}
Let's first calculate that last fraction:
$$\frac{1-iw}{1+iw} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4+2k\pi i}$$
I'm sure you can verify this. Now taking the complex logarithm on both sides yields
\begin{align}
-2iz &= \text{Log}\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}e^{-i\pi/4+2k\pi i}\right) = \ln\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} + i\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k\right)\\
z &= \left(\frac{\pi}{8} + k\pi\right)+\frac{1}{4}i\ln 2
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-\frac{1}{4} i \operatorname{ln}(2)$? Since you divide $\operatorname{ln}(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt 2) = -\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{ln}(2)$ by $-2i = \frac{1}{2}i$?

Comment: You might be right, I dont have time to write it down right now. However that is just 'cleaning up' the answer. The most important thing to take away from my answer is the method for solving these types of problems.

Answer (score 0):

No need to go through the tangent. Note that
$$
\cot z=\frac{\cos z}{\sin z}=
\frac{\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}}{\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}}=
i\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}=i\frac{e^{2iz}+1}{e^{2iz}-1}
$$
so your equation can be rewritten as
$$
ie^{2iz}+i=we^{2iz}-w
$$
or else
$$
e^{2iz}(w-i)=w+i
$$
and finally
$$
e^{2iz}=\frac{w+i}{w-i}
$$
with $w=2+i$. The right-hand side so becomes
$$
\frac{2+i+i}{2+i-i}=1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}
$$
Writing $z=x+iy$, the left-hand side becomes $e^{-2y}e^{2ix}$ and so we get
$$
e^{-2x}=\sqrt{2},\qquad e^{2ix}=e^{i\pi/4}
$$
so $2y=-\log\sqrt{2}$ and $2x=\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi$.